# Activate tweenlite plugins inside class file

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

So I have a public class and I have imported TweenLite into it and it works great but how would I activate a TweenLite plugin? The usual syntax `TweenPlugin.activate([ShortRotation]);` isn't correct in here.

```
package com.George.MegaAmazingApp.Components
{
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    // Import TweenEngine
    import com.greensock.TweenLite;
    import com.greensock.easing.Expo;
    import com.greensock.plugins.ShortRotationPlugin;
    import com.greensock.plugins.TweenPlugin;
```

Error recieved is

> Line 13   1120: **Access of undefined property ShortRotation.**

Comment: Why this usual syntax isn't correct here?

Comment: @Kodiak Line 13 1120: **Access of undefined property ShortRotation.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
TweenPlugin.activate([ShortRotationPlugin]);
```